# Deploy angularjs application in Node.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs

Hello I am following [this tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) from the AngularJS documentation.

I am trying to use this approach for learning this.

> You will need an http server running on your system. Mac and Linux machines typically have Apache pre-installed, but If you don't already have one installed, you can use node to run scripts/web-server.js, a simple bundled http server.

My server is started but the only things that happens on localhost:8000 (the port its running on) is that files get listed.

How do I deploy with Node.js?

When I navigate to localhost:8000 in my browser, this is my server log.

> 112-108-15:scripts phe$ ./web-server.js
>   Http Server running at http://localhost:8000/
>   GET / Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36
>   GET / Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see [the instruction](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00), you need to run

```
node ./scripts/web-server.js
```

and go to `http://localhost:8000/app/index.html`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have node installed, go to the directory where your angular application is and type:

```
scripts/webserver.js
```

hit enter and voila!

You can visit your site at:

`http://localhost:8000/`

If you don't have node installed, install node and then go to the first step.

Comment: I have done this. And got the server started. What url should i use? I am trying http://localhost:8000/

Comment: What happens when you go to that url?

Comment: You're running the command from the wrong directory (the scripts directory). Go up one directory `cd ..` and then type `scripts/web-server.js`

Comment: Now all the folders in angular-phonecat is listed instead.

Comment: so go to localhost:8000/app/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to serve the files from a server on your local machine.

In the docs, it is mentioned you can serve the files from a node server.

However, if you do not want to download and run nodejs, and you are on Mac/Linux you have python already installed, you can also `cd` into the directory with `index.html` and run a python server - `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`. This will serve the files on port 8000. Go to localhost:8000 and you will see your files being rendered.

And, if you want to deploy it to production on a remote machine, I came across [deployment of nodejs & angular application deployment to production using ansible.](http://blog.apcelent.com/node-js-mongodb-angularjs-web-development-deployent.html) I used the same to deploy my first app to production.

Comment: are you "the" Elon Musk who owns Tesla?